# How can I get "->function('xxx','xxx')" in the end of some text

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to get one or more `->func(xxx,xxx)` at the end of a piece of code.

Their could be like this:

```
any code any code ->func(xxx)
```

or

```
any code any code 
->func()
```

or

```
any code any code 
-funcA()->funcB(xxx)
```

or

```
any code any code 
->funcA()
->funcB(xxx)
```

or mix them:

```
o.start_time = obj.s;
o.repair_type -> obj.r;
o.limit -> obj.l;->god("('\"\"')") ->fox(,'->')
->egg()->dog(,'c')
->cat(,'b')-> banana(,'a"\'\(\)\'->"()')  ->  apple(,'a')
```

In this code, i want to :

- plan A

  1. get substring `apple(,'a')`
  2. remove `->  apple(,'a')`
  3. get substring `banana(,'a"\'\(\)\'->"()')`
  4. remove `-> banana(,'a"\'\(\)\'->"()')`
  5. get substring `cat(,'b')`
  6. remove `->cat(,'b')`
  7. get substring `dog(,'c')`
  8. remove `->dog(,'c')`
  9. get `egg()`
  10. remove `->egg()`
  11. get `fox(,'->')`
  12. remove `->fox(,'->')`
  13. get `god("('\"\"')")god("('\"\"')")`
  14. remove `->god("('\"\"')")`
  15. OVER
- plan B:

  1. get and remove `->cat(,'b')-> banana(,'a"\'\(\)\'->"()')  ->  apple(,'a')`

     1. get substring `apple(,'a')`
     2. remove `->  apple(,'a')`
     3. get substring `banana(,'a"\'\(\)\'->"()')`
     4. remove `-> banana(,'a"\'\(\)\'->"()')`
     5. get substring `cat(,'b')`
     6. remove `->cat(,'b')`
  2. get and remove `->egg()->dog(,'c')`

     1. get substring `dog(,'c')`
     2. remove `->dog(,'c')`
     3. get `egg()`
     4. remove `->egg()`
  3. get and remove `->god("('\"\"')") ->fox(,'->')`

     1. get `fox(,'->')`
     2. remove `->fox(,'->')`
     3. get `god("('\"\"')")god("('\"\"')")`
     4. remove `->god("('\"\"')")`
  4. OVER

Now, I am trying planB by this two RegEx, but not good enough:

```
loop
    if match "\R\s*->\s*(.+)$"
        get substring and remove
        loop substring
        if match "(?:(?<=\)).)*\s*->\s*(((?!->).)*)$"
            push substring2 to arr
            remove substring2
        else
            break
    else
        break
```

Comment: why is this tagged javascript?

Comment: you might have forgotten to tag `c++`, `c` and several other programming languages...

Comment: @KevinEsche Stackoverflow does not allow more than 5 tags otherwise we would have seen them all

Comment: oh, I though people can fix this problem no matter what languages he is familiar with. Am I wrong? I remove tags right now. Sorry.

Comment: tagging programming language is important. it lets us know which regex parser we are dealing with. now to the problem: if the functions can be "nested" like `func('func(\'\')')` it may not necessarily be a regular grammar  and in that case LL or LR parser will be required.

Comment: So, it is PCRE? I see `\R` construct in the regex...

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew   yes, veteran. http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

Comment: What a mess of a regex I have... Try [`(?:\s*->\s*[\w.]+(\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?1))*\)))+\s*\z`](https://regex101.com/r/xI4bZ5/1).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thank you so much, I modify some place, and now it is in line with my request: (?:(\s*->\s*([\w.]+\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?1))*\))))+\s*\z

Comment: I cannot understand what you did without proper formatting. I suspect you made an error there by adding another capturing group and keeping the former subroutine call. Shall I post my regex?

Comment: But it seems to work fine? [`(?:(\s*->\s*([\w.]+\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?1))*\))))+\s*\z`](https://regex101.com/r/xI4bZ5/2)

Comment: Have you considered to use a PHP parser? A regex can't do the job reliably. Regardless how complicated it get's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think a regex is the final means to match what you need, but it can be used for a one-off task.

In PCRE, we have a recursion support, thus we can match function start and end. **If the code does not have any comments**, you can match these nested `(...)` together with single- and double-quoted string literals  at the end of the string with

```
(?:((?(3)\s*|\R*)->\s*([\w.]*(\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"‌​|[^"'()]++|(?3))*\)))))+\s*\z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xI4bZ5/7)

*Explanation*:

- `(?:((?(3)\s*|\R*)->\s*([\w.]*(\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"‌​|[^"'()]++|(?3))*\)))))+` - 1 or more occurrences of the following sequences:

  - `(?(3)\s*|\R*)` - a *conditional* that checks if Group 3 matched, and matches 0+ whitespace characters if Group 3 is initialized, and matches 0+ linebreak sequences (with `\R*`) if Group 3 has not matched yet (thus, we match linebreaks only at the start)
  - `->\s*` - `->` followed with 0+ whitespace
  - `([\w.]*)` - (Group 1, *function name*) 0+ alphanumeric/underscore/dot characters
  - `(\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?1))*\))` - Group 1 matching

    - `\(`  - literal opening `(`
    - `(?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?3))*` - single quoted literals (`'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'`) or double-quoted literals (`"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`) or `(...)` (`[^"'()]++|(?3)` where `(?3)` recurses the whole Group 3 subpattern).
    - `\)`  - literal closing `)`
- `\s*\z` - 0+ whitespace `\s*` right before the very end of the string `\z`.

Comment: but this expression only match the capturing group like "(xxx)" but lost funcion name. and this can work good: [`(?:(\s*->\s*([\w.]+\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?1))*\))))+\s*\z`](https://regex101.com/r/xI4bZ5/2)

Comment: So, you need that `apple`? Then, you need to use [`(?:\s*->\s*([\w.]+)(\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?2))*\)))+\s*\z`](https://regex101.com/r/xI4bZ5/3)

Comment: Uh! A regex is obviously not the right tool for the job. I suggest use a PHP parser instead.

Comment: Not only `apple(,'a')`, but also need `->  apple(,'a')` ,because I should remove this string from the whole piece of code, so I can get `banana()` next.

Comment: @hek2mgl But I am not writing PHP code. The text before `->func(xx)` could be anything.

Comment: AFAIK only PHP has such a syntax. If using PHP parser does not work, write your own: http://web.iitd.ac.in/~sumeet/flex__bison.pdf

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, but `->(bla, bla)` is PHP specific syntax

Comment: @cjk: Ok, if you need all those capturing groups, here is your fixed pattern: [`(?:(\s*->\s*([\w.]+(\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?3))*\)))))+\s*\z`](https://regex101.com/r/xI4bZ5/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What if the input is: `->("->('foo', 'bar')")` ?? I hope it is clear that a single regex (or two) **can't** do the job.

Comment: @hek2mgl: "what-if" is not for a one-off job. The sample strings in the question is the scope I can suggest a regex for. I also added a disclaimer for code comments. And here is a regex for that case: [`(?:(\s*->\s*([\w.]*(\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?3))*\)))))+\s*\z`](https://regex101.com/r/xI4bZ5/5)

Comment: @hek2mgl I said I am not writing PHP. AFAIK, only fish has the tail, so the dolphin is fish.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, can I make a request more? I don't want to get the `white space` before `->god()` unless it is a new line char.

Comment: Just [replace the first `\s` with `\n`](https://regex101.com/r/xI4bZ5/6). Or `[\r\n]*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is not what I want, I just don't need the `\s` before `->god()`, but need other `\s` before other `->func()`(ignore headmost `\s`, but not the other). replace the first `\s`, all space before `->func()` are miss.

Comment: Try a conditional: [`(?:((?(3)\s*|\R*)->\s*([\w.]*(\((?>'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"'()]++|(?3))*\)))))+\s*\z`](https://regex101.com/r/xI4bZ5/7).

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I'll take time to understand it.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the final pattern/demo and explanations.

Answer (score -1):

The proper answer is, you can't parse a non regular language with a regular expression. You need to either user an existing parser for that language if that exists or write your own.

The now publicly available ["Flex & Bison"](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~sumeet/flex__bison.pdf) O'Reilly is a good read.

Comment: When you say there is no solution, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I don't get you. Sure there is a solution and I suggested that: write a parser. Writing the parser for the OP would exceed an answer and also can be done only if I exactly know the rules of the input language. A single example document is not enough for that.

Comment: Suggestion to write a parser cannot be an answer. That is a comment. If you write a parser, and post it, that would be an answer. If I follow your approach, I should answer every HTML regex parsing question with "Use DOM/(X)HTML parser". What good is such an answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why do you discuss with me? Your solution is plain wrong. The fact that the OP is asking how can I do this **with regex** shows that he never really considered the *right* solution. I pointed him towards it.

Comment: [I told that already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493132/how-can-i-get-functionxxx-xxx-in-the-end-of-some-text/36499566?noredirect=1#comment60606288_36495446) .. If you need more: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

Comment: @hek2mgl I support WS views. And I am not coding PHP. This is my own syntax. I coding a sofeware, thay you select some text has `->func()` in the end. The program will change the text. Like `apple ->append('banana')`=>`apple banana`. So, the text can be anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. If you invent a language, you need to write a parser for that. That's what I'm saying and the book I've linked is a great resource on that. I just said, if that's PHP you might use the *existing* PHP parser. As it now turns out that it is not PHP but something custom, you need to write a parser.

Comment: I don't need to do this job so complicated, put the text into function, job is done.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. Your English is hard to understand.

Comment: I see, my english is a shit ha. Thank you for your answer first. And what I want to do is get those text before `->func()`, and put them in the middle of the brackets. And then `eval('func(xxx)')`.

Comment: You want to use `eval()` on the results of that fragile regex thingy?! That's super-fragile and super-dangerous. You are doing it wrong!